# R: Prevent Overlapping Labels on Graphs in R

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following network graph:

```
 library(tidyverse)
 library(visNetwork)
 library(htmlwidgets)

 set.seed(123)
 mat <- matrix(runif(5*5), nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
mat = round(mat, 2)
 
 
 nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:5)
 edges <- data.frame(from = sample(1:5, 100, replace = TRUE), to = sample(1:5, 100, replace = TRUE))
 
 nodes$shape <- 'circle'
 edges$weight <- apply(edges, 1, function(x) mat[x["from"], x["to"]])
 
 nodes$shape <- 'circle'
 edges$weight <- apply(edges, 1, function(x) mat[x["from"], x["to"]])
 edges$label <- as.character(apply(edges, 1, function(x) mat[x["from"], x["to"]]))
 

 nodes$label = paste("Node", 1:5)
 
 
 network <- visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
     visEdges(arrows = list(to = list(enabled = TRUE))) %>%
     visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout_in_circle") 
 
 network
```

The graph looks something like this:

[image]

**My Question:** I noticed that in some places, some of the edge labels appear to be overlapping each other.

For example, between (3,5) and (5,3) - the label 0.64 completely "masks" the label 0.10.

```
> mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] 0.29 0.05 0.96 0.90 0.89
[2,] 0.79 0.53 0.45 0.25 0.69
[3,] 0.41 0.89 0.68 0.04 0.64
[4,] 0.88 0.55 0.57 0.33 0.99
[5,] 0.94 0.46 0.10 0.95 0.66
```

**Is there any way to prevent this in R?**

Thanks!